# Get data from angular 2 pipe

Tags: templates, angular, pipe, components

Is it possible to get filetered data from pipe to component?

If our data filtered by pipes in template, How I can grab this filtered data and pass it into my component ? :)

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if it's a good think and what is your exact use case but you can inject the component instance (or a shared service) into the pipe constructor.

Then you can set value on it:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'test'
})
export class TestPipe {
  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => AppComponent)) private comp:AppComponent) {

  }

  transform(value) {
    var filtered = value.map((v) => v-1);
    this.comp.filteredData = filtered;
    return filtered;
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/Lp6p97FtytdMM6mA7VGX?p=preview.

Comment: Thierry. My dear friend. Thank you so much! You are awesome! Please, send me on my email (I wroted to you few days ago to your yahoo mail) your webmoney number, I want buy to you a beer! You one man that helped me a lot!

P.S. Where you are got this knowledge. I looking in many source but can`t found anything about forwardRef  for example,  and about others hidden angular2  feautures.

Update. Looked on your github repos. Now I know.